# AuthenticationManager in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an assignment where I have to make an authentication system with passwords hashed and salted with SHA256. I've noticed there isn't a SHA password encoder implementation that I can see, so ive made my own.

I've made filters before for authentication when WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was a thing, using the AuthenticationManager from there, but now that its deprecated, is there a default AuthenticationManager that can be injected into my custom filter?

**The old way you could do it**

```
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

Comment: The SHA-256 Encoders can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e17989d92d2dda884c8a25143a38f14131121d8c/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java#L77-L79

Note that these are not considered secure anymore

Comment: Ill take a look, its just for an assignment, so the only requirement is that it works. Thanks for the resource

Comment: You should also have a look at https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

This blog post explains the migration away from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter very detailed

Comment: The encoder part wasnt the main issue for me however, my issue now is how can I get the AuthenticationManager to set an authenticated user once their credentials are verified. I linked above how I could previously, but now I dont understand where AuthenticationManager comes from if I need it for my filter

Comment: This is described at the end of the aforementioned blog post.
But I don't think you need to write a custom filter. The existing httpBasic and formLogin options provided by Spring Security should be more than enough.

Comment: I just wrote a custom filter because the salt for the user is stored in the db table with the password and I didnt know how to really work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose `AuthenticationManager` as a bean in many ways, for example:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Another:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
    return authManagerBuilder.getOrBuild();
}
```